# File sharing through samba is not working over LAN

Tags: samba, file-sharing

I am getting the following error while running net usershare command.

> 'net usershare' returned error 255: net usershare: cannot open usershare directory /var/lib/samba/usershares. Error Permission denied
>   You do not have permission to create a usershare. Ask your administrator to grant you permissions to create a share.

How to fix this?
Thanks,
:)

Answer (score 17):

The directory `/var/lib/samba/usershares` is set up so only root or members of the `sambashare` group can read or write to it.

```
drwxrwx--T  2 root sambashare  4096 Mar 25  2012 usershares
```

That you can't access it (try it by `cd`ing to it) suggests to me that you're not in the `sambashare` group. You can test this with `id $USER` and assuming `usershares` is not in the output, you can fix all this just by running:

```
sudo usermod -a -G sambashare $USER
```

If you still get error 255 after adding the particular user to the group you might need to reboot.

Comment: Found that the directory is present there with a cross mark onto the folder. though i am being able access other folders in the LAN through SAMBA but not able to share my files to others.

Comment: this is the error while trying to "Create Share" 'net usershare' returned error 255: net usershare: cannot open usershare directory /var/lib/samba/usershares. Error Permission denied
You do not have permission to create a usershare. Ask your administrator to grant you permissions to create a share.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error on Ubuntu 20.04 and this was the way to solve it:

#### Remove all samba related files and configuration files

```
sudo apt purge python3-samba samba-common samba-common-bin samba-dsdb-modules samba samba-vfs-modules smbclient
```

Optionally you can remove the packages and maintain the configuration files, but this could left wrong files in the middle. It's better to do a backup of your configuration files. Anyway, if you want to try it, use `remove` instead of `purge`.

#### Reboot

Not sure if it's completely necessary, but I do it this way.

#### Share files

Open Nautilus and share a file or directory. A warning is showed indicating the sharing service is not installed and allowing you to click to install it. Click, install and you're done!

The nautilus-share package creates the `/var/lib/samba/usershares/` directory with the right permissions and added your user to `sambashare` group, and it's ready to be used by other users too.

Comment: Thankyou this solution worked for me. (I think I had a prior manual Samba installation). After your command I ran `apt install nautilus-share`