# Ubuntu 23.04 Network File Sharing / Windows cannot access \\UBUNTU\Public

Tags: nautilus, samba

I have a clean installation of Ubuntu 23.04 that I'm trying to configure to share the Public folder with a computer running Windows 10 Pro. The Windows computer is able to access shared folders from other computers on my network (Windows 7, Windows 10, Windows Server 2016/2019/2022).

I installed `nautilus-share`. After this, "Sharing Options" appeared in the menu. I tried the options `Allow others to create and delete files in this folder` and `Guest access (for people without a user account)`. Neither made a difference.

[image: This is the error that I'm getting on Windows.]

[image: Windows does not have read permission.]

[image: Here is the Sharing Options menu.]

[image: Here is net usershare info.]

I am able to access the share on Ubuntu using "other locations".

I used `smbpasswd` to set the password.

I created a credential in Windows with the same username and password.

I searched and found quite a few posts about this problem, but no solutions that worked.

If anyone has any suggestions to fix this, I would really appreciate it.

(In case it matters, I am able to access files on the Windows and Windows Server computers from Ubuntu.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit /etc/samba/smb.conf and right under the workgroup = WORKGROUP line add this one:

```
force user = daryl
```

Then restart samba:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

The problem isn't samba it's a change Ubuntu made from 22.04 on that changed the default permissions on a users home folder to 750 meaning no one other than that user can access any of it's contents.

"force user = daryl" will make the "guest" user appear to be you - for these shares.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. Your suggestion fixed the problem.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks! I tested that this also still respects read-only settings even though i am forcing it to be my user: permission denied for write is correctly thrown for guest access.

Answer (score 0):

I did another clean installation to make sure I could get file sharing from Ubuntu to Windows working properly from scratch.

Here are the steps I used from start to finish:

Install nautilus-share:

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y nautilus-share
```

After restarting, the Sharing Options menu was available.

However, when I tried to create a share, there was an error:

> 'net usershare' returned error 255: net usershare: cannot open >usershare directory /var/lib/samba/usershares. Error Permission denied >You do not have permission to create a usershare. Ask your >administrator to grant you permissions to create a share.

[Screen shot of error 255.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Amwdn.png)

I found the fix for this error here: [File sharing through samba is not working over LAN](https://askubuntu.com/questions/251179/file-sharing-through-samba-is-not-working-over-lan)

```
sudo usermod -a -G sambashare $USER
```

After restarting, I was able to create a share.

To test that it was working, I used *+ Other Locations*. It did not accept my credentials because the Samba password had not been set.

I found the fix for the problem here: [Install and Configure Samba](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-samba#4-setting-up-user-accounts-and-connecting-to-share)

```
sudo smbpasswd -a *username*
```

After restarting, I was able access the shared folder and see the contents on Ubuntu.

Now, I was at the point where I started this post, not being able to open the shared folder on Windows. After inserting `force user = daryl` in `smb.conf`, I was able to see the contents of the shared folder on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the post and the answers provided.

In my case, after installed `nautilus-share` and set Samba password, shared the Public folder, all I had to do was opened port 445, the SMB port:

```
sudo ufw allow 445
```

---

I had an exact similar problem: I did a fresh installation of Ubuntu 23.04 Lunar Lobster.

Successfully installed `nautilus-share`, then shared the `/home/behai/Public` folder via Ubuntu 23.04 UI.

I then successfully set Samba password for `behai`, via:

```
sudo smbpasswd -a behai
```

Still, from Windows 10, it refused to connect to `\hp-pavilion-15\Public`, even though it asked for Samba password.

-- `hp-pavilion-15` is my machine / host name.

I did get Windows to do diagnose, but for several hours, it gave me nothing. Finally, during one of those tries, it stated that it can see `hp-pavilion-15` shared files and folders online, but `port 445` refused connection.

---

Another point I have observed, `ufw` seems to be inactive by default? I did enable it and restart the Ubuntu, but `port 445` never entered my mind -- I am not that familiar with Linux.

I hope this helps somebody else.